# iPhone 5 and MacBook Air take quite a few attempts to tether

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi, macbook-pro, tethering

I used to have an iPhone 4 which, when WiFi hotspot was turned on, would connect to my Air (Lion) almost instantaneously.

I have now upgraded to an iPhone 5 (iOS 7) and the process seems to rarely work. I must turn Wifi and Hotspot off and on maybe 10 times in a row before they connect. Sometimes it wont work and at all. Other times it will randomly disconnect.

Would anyone know why this is occurring?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it by going to **System Preferences** → **Sharing** and checking the box for **Internet Sharing**.